# Vue - Async/Await all axios.get before rendering

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to batch `async` `await` all api calls inside a `created()` before rendering the HTML? Please see example code below.

**template.vue**

```
  <template>
      <div v-if="isLoading> //insert skeleton loader </div>
      <div v-else> // insert HTML </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      async created() {
        this.IS_LOADING(true)

        await { 
        // all api calls
        this.functionA
        this.functionB
        }

        // then proceed to setTimeout to remove loading status
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.IS_LOADING(false);
        },2000)
      },

      computed: {
        ...mapState([
          'isLoading'
        ]),

      methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
          'IS_LOADING'
        ]),
        functionA() {}
        functionB() {}
    </script>
```

Comment: Have a look at [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 1):

You can put 2 `await` key, however make sure function A and B is promise function

For more info : check https://javascript.info/async-await

```js
<script>
      async created() {
        this.IS_LOADING(true)

        let responseA = await this.functionA;
        let responseB = await this.functionB;

        // then proceed to setTimeout to remove loading status
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.IS_LOADING(false);
        },2000)
      },

      computed: {
        ...mapState([
          'isLoading'
        ]),

      methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
          'IS_LOADING'
        ]),
        functionA() {}
        functionB() {}
 </script>
```

```html
 <template>
      <div v-if="isLoading>insert skeleton loader </div>
      <div v-else>insert HTML </div>
</template>
```

However, in my own experience, put async key in front of created() will lead to some unexpected , i recommend wrap all of them in a function and call it

```
created(){
 this.getDataAndRender();
},

methods:{
 async getDataAndRender() {
  /// put your logic here

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> An async function (Ex: Your **async created() {}**) can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function to wait for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, then resumes the async function's execution and evaluates
>   as the resolved value.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

So, the following way should solve your problem:

```
  async created() {
    this.IS_LOADING(true)

    await this.functionA
    await this.functionB

    this.IS_LOADING(false);
  }
```

Note: functionA and functionB should return a Promises

ex:

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  console.log("starting slow promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("slow")
      console.log("slow promise is done")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function resolveAfter1Second() {
  console.log("starting fast promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("fast")
      console.log("fast promise is done")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function sequentialStart() {
  console.log('==SEQUENTIAL START==')

  // 1. Execution gets here almost instantly
  const slow = await resolveAfter2Seconds()
  console.log(slow) // 2. this runs 2 seconds after 1.

  const fast = await resolveAfter1Second()
  console.log(fast) // 3. this runs 3 seconds after 1.
}

sequentialStart()
```